# mysql installment insertation kind

Tags: mysql

for example I have a computer. I want to sell with 3 installments worth $300 with post machine
should I insert database like account table

```
 +---------------+--------+------------+
|  DESCRIPTION  | AMOUNT | VALUE DATE |
+---------------+--------+------------+
| INSTALLMENT   |    100 | 01.03.2018 |
| COMMİSSİON    |      1 | 01.03.2018 |
| INSTALLMENT   |    100 | 01.04.2018 |
| COMMİSSİON    |      1 | 01.04.2018 |
| INSTALMENT    |    100 | 01.05.2018 |
| COMMISSION    |      1 | 01.05.2018 |
+---------------+--------+------------+
```

Or insert like this

```
+--------+-------------+--------+-----------+------------+
| amount | installment | perday | commision | startdate  |
+--------+-------------+--------+-----------+------------+
|    300 |           3 |     30 | 1%        | 01.03.2018 |
+--------+-------------+--------+-----------+------------+
```

İf second is more efficent and good then , when I query second table ,how I want to get like first table.

Comment: *İf second is more efficent and good* Hardly... *when I query second table ,how I want to get like first table* Impossible. Conversion (table 1)->(table 2) loose information partially, so it cannot be reversed.

Comment: then you choose first type insertation

Answer (score 0):

The choices are more for your convenience, not the database's ability to handle it.

Here's another:

```
+---------------+--------+------------+------------+
|  DESCRIPTION  | AMOUNT | COMMİSSİON | VALUE DATE |
+---------------+--------+------------+------------+
| INSTALLMENT   |    100 |          1 | 01.03.2018 |
| INSTALLMENT   |    100 |          1 | 01.04.2018 |
| INSTALLMENT   |    100 |          1 | 01.05.2018 |
```

This has the advantage of tying the AMOUNT and COMMISSION together.